# Как вывести на печать данные из StringGrid?

Tags: delphi

Если можно, то с кодом.

Comment: Из самого StringGrid на печать не знаю как вывести. Может сначала вывести в Excel, а потом распечатать?

Comment: Можно и так) А как это сделать, не подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Вывод данных из `StringGrid` в лист `Excel`.
**Не забываем в раздел Uses подключить модуль `ComObj`!!!**
Вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  ExcelApp,
  ExcelSheet,
  ExcelCol,
  ExcelRow: Variant;
  Size: Byte;
  i, j, N, M: Word;
begin
  // Запускаю приложение Excel
  ExcelApp:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  ExcelApp.Visible:=True;

  // Создаю рабочую книгу
  ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(-4167);
  ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[1].Name:='Отчёт';
  ExcelCol:=ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets['Отчёт'].Columns;

  Size:=StringGrid1.DefaultRowHeight; // Ширина ячейки
  N:=StringGrid1.ColCount-1; // Число ячеек в строке
  //Если StringGrid содержит переменное число строк, то пользуемся циклом:
  For j:=0 To N Do
    ExcelCol.Columns[j+1].ColumnWidth:=Size;

  ExcelRow:=ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets['Отчёт'].Rows;
  ExcelRow.Rows[1].Font.Bold:=True; // Заголовки столбцов - жирные

  // Ввод данных в лист Excel из StringGrid
  ExcelSheet:=ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets['Отчёт'];
  For i:=0 To StringGrid1.RowCount-1 Do
    For j:=0 To StringGrid1.ColCount-1 Do
        ExcelSheet.Cells[i+1, j+1]:=StringGrid1.Cells[j, i];
end;
```

Comment: Можно, конечно, ещё, как вариант, вывести на печать данные из StringGrid, используя его канву и канву принтера, но, тогда нельзя будет что-то поправить, отредактировать, как в случае с Excel.

Comment: Не самый удачный алгоритм переноса со StingGrid  в Exel .
Если записей будет 1000 а полей в записи 10 то переноситься будет пол дня.
Рекомендую вместо отдельно переносить каждую ячейку, переносить диапазоном.

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант вывода из StringGrid в CSV , а уже из CSV печатайте

```
var
    Out:TstringList;
    i,j:integer;
    s:String;
    begin
    Out:=TstingList.create; 
    for i:=0 to StringGid1.RowCounter-1 do
     begin
      s:='';
       for j:= 0 to ColCounter-1 do s:=s+StringGrid.Cells[j,i]+';';
       Out.Add(s);  
      end;
     out.SaveToFile('out.csv');
     out.free;
    end;
```

Писал прямо здесь, так что возможны ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо всем) Буду пробовать)

Comment: SoftR, получилось напечатать, только теперь как сделать линии между ячейками, чтобы было похоже на таблицу??

Comment: Ну как вариант откройте CSV в Excell обремените его линиями и печатайте с Excell.

Вообще для вывода табличных данных принято использовать генераторы отчетов,типа FastReopt и тп

Можно городить огород самому, брать Image рисовать на канве таблицу выводить данные и печатать уже с Image но это еще тот геморой.

Еще один Вариант генерируйте HTML код Вашей таблицы и печатайте с браузера, не самый сложный вариант, но и не самый красивый.

Comment: А, если, например требуется вывести заголовки жирным шрифтом (или, если заголовки уже есть в документе Excel, то как начать вывод с определённой строки). Как это сделать при помощи CVS, подскажите пожалуйста, если можно? Мне это для формирования отчёта надо. Я ещё один вариант вывода данных в Excel пробовал: с использованием серверов автоматизации COM.

Comment: **CSV** Это одна из разновидностей формата текстового файла, а именно текстовый файл разделитель ";".
То есть у текста нет атрибута шрифтов, так что с выделение заголовка шрифтом ничего не получиться, если нужно поддержка шрифтов смотрите в сторону **RTF/HTML**
А для того чтобы начать выводить со **StringGrid** с определенной строки то достаточно в строке

     for i:=0 to StringGid1.RowCounter-1 do

0 заменить на номер нужной строки, помня что строки в StringGrid нумеруются с нуля.