# Запись в файл содержимого нескольких StringGrid

Tags: delphi

На форме расположено 4 элемента `StringGrid`. Как записать содержимое всех четырех элементов в файл? И так же потом считать содержимое файла и внести все данные в `StringGrid`'ы автоматически с сохранением размерности таблиц и последовательностью данных?

Answer (score 2):

На [этой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/40661/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-stringgrid?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#40666)
можно посмотреть вывод данных из StringGrid в файлы Excel (два способа).

Answer (score 1):

*Пример желаемого действия с просторов гугла:*

```
// Save a TStringGrid to a file

procedure SaveStringGrid(StringGrid: TStringGrid; const FileName: TFileName);
 var
   f:    TextFile;
   i, k: Integer;
 begin
   AssignFile(f, FileName);
   Rewrite(f);
   with StringGrid do
   begin
     // Write number of Columns/Rows 
    Writeln(f, ColCount);
     Writeln(f, RowCount);
     // loop through cells 
    for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
       for k := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
         Writeln(F, Cells[i, k]);
   end;
   CloseFile(F);
 end;

 // Load a TStringGrid from a file

procedure LoadStringGrid(StringGrid: TStringGrid; const FileName: TFileName);
 var
   f:          TextFile;
   iTmp, i, k: Integer;
   strTemp:    String;
 begin
   AssignFile(f, FileName);
   Reset(f);
   with StringGrid do
   begin
     // Get number of columns 
    Readln(f, iTmp);
     ColCount := iTmp;
     // Get number of rows 
    Readln(f, iTmp);
     RowCount := iTmp;
     // loop through cells & fill in values 
    for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
       for k := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
       begin
         Readln(f, strTemp);
         Cells[i, k] := strTemp;
       end;
   end;
   CloseFile(f);
 end;

 // Save StringGrid1 to 'c:\temp.txt':

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   SaveStringGrid(StringGrid1, 'c:\temp.txt');
 end;

 // Load StringGrid1 from 'c:\temp.txt':

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   LoadStringGrid(StringGrid1, 'c:\temp.txt');
 end;
```

Comment: Код справедлив для записи содержимого только одного StringGrid, мне же нужно запиать содержимое четырех.

Comment: Спасибо! Наконец разабрался как сделать:

Comment: И так далее...

 procedure SaveStringGrid(StringGridA, StringGridB: TStringGrid; const FileName: TFileName);
  var
    f:    TextFile;
    i, k: Integer;
  begin
    AssignFile(f, FileName);
    Rewrite(f);
    with StringGridA do
    begin
   // Write number of Columns/Rows
  Writeln(f, ColCount);
   Writeln(f, RowCount);
   // loop through cells
  for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
     for k := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
       Writeln(F, Cells[i, k]);
    end;

    with StringGridB do
    begin
   .................................
   .................................
    CloseFile(F);
  end;

Comment: [**Ясненько.**][1]

[1]: http://lurkmore.ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#K.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4